# Search for specific page using semantic ui pagination

Tags: pagination, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to get a text box and enter button to go to a certain page in my paginated table using semantic ui here is what I have thus far.

```
<div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                  <Pagination
                        activePage={currentPage}
                        ellipsisItem={{ content: <Icon name='ellipsis horizontal' />, icon: true }}
                        firstItem={{ content: <Icon name='angle double left' />, icon: true }}
                        lastItem={{ content: <Icon name='angle double right' />, icon: true }}
                        prevItem={{ content: <Icon name='angle left' />, icon: true }}
                        nextItem={{ content: <Icon name='angle right' />, icon: true }}

                        onPageChange={this.handlePaginationChange}
                        totalPages={totalPages}
                    />
                </div>
```

I was hoping semantic would provide a text box and button that would fit along the other buttons

Comment: That is for Semantic UI React, right?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I am starting to get to know Semantic UI (jquery version) but I would bet there's no that kind of implementation in Semantic. There are some controls that are implemented just in the HTML side. You can also post a quesiton in the Semantic UI's GitHub site and try to get an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need the answer for it. I had the same question earlier today and I found your post here, but after doing some implementation I figured out the solution.

So basically what I did was to have an input component and a pagination component together inside a form such like:

```js
<Form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
 <Form.Field inline>
  <input
   maxLength={5}
   size={3}
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
   value={inputPage}
   placeholder="page"
  />
    
  <Pagination
   activePage={targetPage !== null ? targetPage : activePage}
   defaultActivePage={defaultPage}
   totalPages={totalPages}
   onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
  />
 </Form.Field>
</Form>
```

so basically you can have a controlled pagination for semantic ui react pagination like so. For each of the call back function you can do something like this:

```js
handleInputChange = (e) => { // Set the e.target.value to a state variable }

handlePageChange = (e) => { // Handle data on page change }
onFormSubmit = e => { // Handle data on page change }
```

So basically you have two functions that will handle the page change, one is for when you click on a certain page on the pagination itself, another one is for when you input a specific page.